# WCF Oracle adaptor and UDT

Tags: wcf, oracle, biztalk

Is there any way to work with Oracle UDT's with current WCF adaptor?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly, you want to express Oracle user defined types in WCF services?  This will really depend on the protocol to be used.  For example, if you are using one of the SOAP protocols like the WS* protocols, then you are stuck with those data types that are defined in SOAP.  Going from any data type, whether it be a built in type in your database, a custom type in C#, or a user defined type in SQL Server, Oracle, whatever, you will have this limitation.  Your simple types will prolly map to something *less complex* like a numeric or a string.  If you have a complex type you may opt to write your own serialization for the type.